# cannot find/read/delete new notifications on lock screen

Tags: 17.10, notification, lock-screen

In Ubuntu 17.10 the lock screen tells me that there is a new notification from Backups and another from the Software Manager. However I don't see how I can view those notifications. When I start Backups or the Software Manager no notification is shown.

Answer (score 15):

Press super + m and you get to the menu you need.
You can see/read the messages **and** delete them.

Answer (score 7):

Thank you, @DeZett. Meanwhile I have found another way: click on the date/time display in the center top of the screen to get to the same menu as with super+m.